# sql query with left join in php don't work

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I made a SQL query in my database and it works perfectly, but when I try to put this same query into PHP, it doesn't work. I cannot figure out where is the error.

```
//connection variables
$host = "localhost";
$database = "kjnjkyeo3";
$user = "root";
$pass = "probajovo11";

//connection to the database
$connection = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass, $database)
or die ('cannot connect to the database: ' . mysql_error());


$sql = "SELECT ps_orders.id_order, ps_order_detail.id_order, ps_order_detail.product_reference AS Itemno,  ps_order_detail.product_quantity AS Saleqty, ROUND(ps_order_detail.total_price_tax_incl, 2) AS Cost, DATE_FORMAT(ps_orders.date_add , \'%Y%m%dT%T\' ) AS Dateoftrans\n"
    . "FROM ps_orders\n"
    . "LEFT JOIN kjnjkyeo3.ps_order_detail ON ps_orders.id_order = ps_order_detail.id_order";

//loop to show all the tables and fields
$loop = mysql_query($sql)
or die ('cannot select tables');
```

I made a lot of changes in my query but I always get the message `cannot select tables`. When I make a simple query like `Select tables from $database`, it works fine.

---

I made the changes:

```
//connection variables
$host = "localhost";
$database = "kjnjkyeo3";
$user = "root";
$pass = "probajovo11";

//connection to the database
$connection = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass)
or die ('cannot connect to the database: ' . mysql_error());

//select the database
mysql_select_db($database)
or die ('cannot select database: ' . mysql_error());

$sql = "SELECT ps_orders.id_order, ps_order_detail.id_order, ps_order_detail.product_reference AS Itemno,  ps_order_detail.product_quantity AS Saleqty, ROUND(ps_order_detail.total_price_tax_incl, 2) AS Cost, DATE_FORMAT(ps_orders.date_add , \'%Y%m%dT%T\' ) AS Dateoftrans FROM ps_orders LEFT JOIN ps_order_detail ON ps_orders.id_order = ps_order_detail.id_order";

//loop to show all the tables and fields
$loop = mysql_query($sql)
or die ('cannot select tables');
```

but it still doesn't work

Comment: whats are the "\n" on the querys ?

Comment: i made this query directly in mysql database and i generate the sql statment with the option in database and he puts the \n.

Comment: are you sure database is a he? Think about it, it may be she :P

Comment: :), i am not a native english speaker

Answer (score 1):

```
$connection = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die ('cannot connect to the database: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($database);
$sql = "SELECT ps_orders.id_order, ps_order_detail.id_order,
 ps_order_detail.product_reference AS Itemno,  ps_order_detail.product_quantity AS Saleqty, ROUND(ps_order_detail.total_price_tax_incl, 2) AS Cost, DATE_FORMAT(ps_orders.date_add , \'%Y%m%dT%T\' ) AS Dateoftrans FROM ps_orders LEFT JOIN kjnjkyeo3.ps_order_detail ON ps_orders.id_order = ps_order_detail.id_order";
```

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_connect` doesn't allow you to select the database like you are doing. You have to use `mysql_select_db` and one day you'll also have to eventually move to `mysqli` or `PDO`.

```
$connection = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die ('cannot connect to the database: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($database);
```

Answer (score 0):

mysql_connect does not take a $database parameter. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php, instead use:

```
$connection = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass)
mysql_select_db($database, $connection)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [mysql_select_db($database)](https://www.php.net/mysql_select_db) to tell on which databases will the queries run.

If you are selecting from multiple databases you can use this way of referecing a field

> ```
> `database_name`.`table_name`.`field_name`
> ```

or just

```
`database_name`.`table_name`
```

for a table in FROM.

mysql_* functions are deprecated, if you are starting a new project use mysqli or pdo